# Occasionally get undefined after setting values via service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have public fields in service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ShareDataService {
  // some code

    public templateForCurrencyCOS;
    public templateForPercentCOS;
    public templateForCurrencyCOGS;
    public templateForPercentCOGS;

 // some code
}
```

In fact values for this fields get set in `HeaderComponent` by subscribing to other `revenueService`:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private revenueService: RevenueService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addCOSItemCurrencyTemplate();
    this.addCOSItemPercentTemplate();
    this.addCOGSItemCurrencyTemplate();
    this.addCOGSItemPercentTemplate();
  }

  addCOSItemCurrencyTemplate() {
    if (!this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOS) { 
      this.revenueService.addCostOfSellingItemCurrencyNew().subscribe( 
        response => {
          this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOS = response;
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    }

    addCOSItemPercentTemplate() {
      if (!this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOS) {
        this.revenueService.addCOSPercentNew().subscribe(response =>{ 
          this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOS = response;
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }

    addCOGSItemCurrencyTemplate() {
      // similar implementation like addCOSItemPercentTemplate and addCOSItemCurrencyTemplate
    }

    addCOGSItemPercentTemplate() {
      // similar implementation like addCOSItemPercentTemplate and addCOSItemCurrencyTemplate
    }      
  }        
}
```

Here **from time to time** I get `undefined` for 
   `this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOGS` as well as for 
   `this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOS`, 
   `this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOGS`, 
   `this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOS`

```
export class RevenueAssistantComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {

    this.templateForCurrencyCOGS = {...
      this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOGS,
      fields: [...this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOGS.fields]
    };

     this.templateForPercentCOGS = {... 
       this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOGS,
       fields: [...this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOGS && this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOGS.fields]
      };
      this.templateForCurrencyCOS = {
        ...this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOS,
        fields: [...this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOS && this.shareDataService.templateForCurrencyCOS.fields]
      };
      this.templateForPercentCOS = {
        ...this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOS,
        fields: [...this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOS && 
        this.shareDataService.templateForPercentCOS.fields]
     };
  }
}
```

I guess the reason behind this issue in `RevenueAssistantComponent` inits before `HeaderComponent` sets value for fields and way to resolve that is 
 `RevenueAssistantComponent` get templates values **always after** in `HeaderComponent` set values for  `shareDataService` fields. But I have no idea how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Initializing at the time of Declaring will resolve the errors.

```
public templateForCurrencyCOS = {}; or templateForCurrencyCOS = []; // for Arrays
public templateForPercentCOS = {};
public templateForCurrencyCOGS = {};
public templateForPercentCOGS = {};
```

Comment: But I get `Property 'fields' does not exist on type '{}'`

Comment: It does not fix issue